# How do I pass header in appsync mutate for an amplify project

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have below code for an appsync mutate call. Where I am trying to pass header.

```
const result =  await client.mutate(buildMutation(
        client,
        gql(createTodo),
        {
          inputType: gql(createTodoInput),
          variables: {
            input: selectedTodo
          },
          context: {
            headers: {
              'x-appsync-domain': environment.host,
            },
          },
        },
        _variables => [gql(listTodo)],
        "Todo"
      ));
```

However, I am getting error on the context. May I know where can I pass the context?